# How to replace tokens on a string template?

Tags: c#, template-engine

I'm attempting to learn to write a basic template engine implementation.  For example I have a string:

```
string originalString = "The current Date is: {{Date}}, the time is: {{Time}}";
```

what is the best way of reading the contents of each `{{}}` and then replacing the whole token with the valid string?

EDIT: Thanks to BrunoLM for pointing me in the right direction, so far this is what I have and it parses just fine, is there any other things I can do to optimize this function?

```
private const string RegexIncludeBrackets = @"{{(.*?)}}";

public static string ParseString(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, RegexIncludeBrackets, match =>
    {
        string cleanedString = match.Value.Substring(2, match.Value.Length - 4).Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        switch (cleanedString)
        {
            case "Date":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/d");
            case "Time":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            case "DateTime":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            default:
                return match.Value;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to make an effort!!!. A simple google search will do

Comment: here is the hint, read `boxing/unboxing` and `String.Format` from msdn

Comment: possible duplicate of [template engine implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916099/template-engine-implementation)

Comment: @BrunoLM I would gladly help if the OP shows even the slightest sign of making an effort to solve his problem. I am wondering why this is coming from a 20k+ rep user

Comment: @BrunoLM http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better/179038#179038

Comment: @BrunoLM Well your answer had `+1/-1`. That shows little or nobody agrees with it. The other answer has `+52/-0`. Thats shows 52 people agree with it and nobody disagrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

I think it would be best to use a Regex.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"{{(?<Name>[^}]+)}}", m =>
{
    return m.Groups["Name"].Value; // Date, Time
});
```

---

On [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) you can use:

```
string result = $"Time: {DateTime.Now}";
```

---

### String.Format & IFormattable

However, there is a method for that already. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
String.Format("The current Date is: {0}, the time is: {1}", date, time);
```

And also, you can use a class with `IFormattable`. I didn't do performance tests but this one might be fast:

```
public class YourClass : IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (format == "Date")
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/d");
        if (format == "Time")
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        if (format == "DateTime")
            return DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return format;

        // or throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And use as

```
String.Format("The current Date is: {0:Date}, the time is: {0:Time}", yourClass);
```

---

### Review of your code and detailed information

In your current code you are using

```
// match.Value = {{Date}}
match.Value.Substring(2, match.Value.Length - 4).Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

Instead, if you look at my code above, I used the pattern

```
@"{{(?<Name>[^}]+)}}"
```

The syntax `(?<SomeName>.*)` means this is a [named group, you can check the documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression)

It allows you to access `match.Groups["SomeName"].Value` which will be equivalent to the pattern with this group. So it would match two times, returning "Date" and then "Time", so you don't need to use `SubString`.

Updating your code, it would be

```
private const string RegexIncludeBrackets = @"{{(?<Param>.*?)}}";

public static string ParseString(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, RegexIncludeBrackets, match =>
    {
        string cleanedString = match.Groups["Param"].Value.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        switch (cleanedString)
        {
            case "Date":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/d");
            case "Time":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            case "DateTime":
                return DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            default:
                return match.Value;
        }
    });
}
```

To improve even more, you can have a static compiled Regex field:

```
private static Regex RegexTemplate = new Regex(@"{{(?<Param>.*?)}}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

And then use as

```
RegexTemplate.Replace(str, match => ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I took your initial idea on regex and added on it