# string format custom parameter

Tags: c#, formatting, string-formatting, string.format

Is there a (simple/predefined) way to use the same `string.format` mechanism but use names instead of numbers? I want to use the same formatting system but make it more end-user friendly. Right now my users are putting in `{0} {1:Minutes}` after selecting what parameters they want to use from a list but it becomes quite unreadable and confusing once you start using more then say 2 parameters.

For example want to do `{Now}` and `{Now:Minutes}` and have it replaced with DateTime.Now for `{Now}` and `DateTime.Now.Minutes` using the IFormattable for `{Now:Minutes}`. So that the users won't need to select items from a list anymore but rather just type/insert the names of the parameters.

Comment: Just roll your own method using [string.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: look at some of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311509/string-format-descriptive-text, especially [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21312156/451540)

Comment: [This](http://humanizr.net/) might be useful to you.

Comment: Whilst perhaps not immediately useful to you unless you're using the VS2015 CTP, C# is getting string interpolation which should give you exactly what you need in the future. You can read about it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace tokens on a string template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651754/how-to-replace-tokens-on-a-string-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) you can use

```
string result = $"Time: {DateTime.Now}";
```

---

On previous versions see

- [How to replace tokens on a string template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20651798/340760)